# How to run an Intel MPI RDMA application on Azure within two CentOS A8 VM instances

Tags: azure, centos, mpi, intel, rdma

I can't seem to figure out how to run an Intel MPI RDMA application on Azure within two CentOS A8 VM instances.

I am trying to test the RDMA setup on my two Azure A8 virtual machines (VM1, VM2) on the same private network `10.1.1.0/24`. Note that, as mentioned in [Azure doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-hpc#rdma-capable-instances) each VM has another interface within address space `172.16.0.0/16`. I also have followed the guidelines to setup [basic two node cluster to run mpi application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/classic/rdma-cluster#run-mpi-on-a-basic-two-node-cluster), but I don't have a pingpong application on CentOS to test with. Basically, I was never able to test the RDMA setup for two nodes. So, I jumped to create a simple application following [this Example 2](https://github.com/jcxue/RDMA-Tutorial/wiki) with a few tweaks to run it on my VMs.

```
mpirun -ppn 1 -n 2 -hosts VM1,VM2 -env I_MPI_FABRICS=shm:dapl -env I_MPI_DAPL_PROVIDER=ofa-v2-ib0 -env I_MPI_DYNAMIC_CONNECTION=0 ./rdma-tutorial 6011
```

The above command will run the rdma-tutorial application on socket `6011` on both VM1 and VM2. The application main reads a file (client_file) to know if the running VM is server or client. The file exists on VM2 (but not on VM1), so VM2 is the client, and the file contains the name of VM1 as server. On VM1 (server) it opens 6011 socket and waits for the QP (queue pair) info from the VM2 (client). On VM2, it sends the QP info to VM1. After sharing the QP info the code hangs and never finishes. Looking at pstack and using gdb I understand that the application is waiting to receive message from the other side. Note that, VMs use `eth0` on `10.1.1.0/24` to share the QP info.

My understanding is that once the QP info are shared, two VMs will be communicating over the eth1(172.16.0.0/16) network. Is this correct? If so, I suppose `ethtool -S eth1` should show growing counts for `tx_queue_0_packets` and `tx_queue_0_bytes`. But unfortunately, they are stuck: [Image: `ethtool -S eth1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnJkF.png)

RDMA is enabled on both VMs [Image: RDMA enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sma6y.png)

Also note that the VMs are not reachable with ping on `172.16.0.0/16`. I also have tried `rping`, but that too hangs.

Is there anything that I am missing? Should VM1 be able to ping VM2 over `172.16.0.0/16`? What are the next things I should try?